# How to pass my view model to a user to main view model?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, relaycommand

I made a main window that displays various user controls in a content control.  In this window, I have the user controls and their accompanying view models in the XAML as DataTemplate Resources.  This window has a button that needs to display the user control in the contentcontrol and instantiate the view model for it.  How can i pass the resource to my RelayCommand, so that i can tell the command which user control and view model to use?  I figured out how to pass a hard-coded string as the command parameter, but now I'm wanting to pass the x:Name so i can reuse this command etc for more than one View-ViewModel.

Main Window's XAML snippets:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--User Controls and Accompanying View Models-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EmployerSetupVM:EmployerSetupVM}" x:Key="EmployerSetup" x:Name="EmployerSetup">
        <EmployerSetupView:EmployerSetupView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VendorSetupVM:VendorSetupVM}">
        <VendorSetupView:VendorSetupView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource EmployerSetup}">
```

...
In the Main Window's ViewModel, here relevant code so far:

```
public RelayCommand<DataTemplate> ShowCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

ShowCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => ShowExecuted(s));



private void ShowExecuted(DataTemplate s)
    {
        var fred = (s.DataType);  //how do i get the actual name here, i see it when i hover with intellisense, but i can't access it!


        if (!PageViewModels.Contains(EmployerSetupVM))
        {
            EmployerSetupVM = new EmployerSetupVM();
            PageViewModels.Add(EmployerSetupVM);
        }

        int i = PageViewModels.IndexOf(EmployerSetupVM);

        ChangeViewModel(PageViewModels[i]);
    }
```

...
in other words, how do i get the name of the my DataTemplate w/ x:Key="EmployerSetup" in the XAML?    If it matters, I'm using MVVMLight  too

Comment: so how does this `Button` know if it should pass `VendorSetupVM` or `EmployerSetupVM`. I don't follow your question and your xaml and VM code aint in sync. In xaml your binding to `EmployerSetupCommand` while in .cs that's called `ShowCommand` I guess? What's `PageViewModels` and why are you in that function only checking for `EmployerSetupVM`. Just type some pseudo-code of what your expecting in a clear way. No clue what's even going on in this.  Don't really see the benefit of reusing a command with all this complexity tbh. I'd just have 2 commands and switch the Binding in the Button Style.

Comment: sorry, I edited to make the command names correct etc.  My question is how to correctly use CommandParameter to tell the function which ViewModel I should have the code change the current view model to.  PageViewModels is simply a collection of ViewModels.

Comment: basically I just need to know, if I pass the DataTemplate "EmployerSetup" which respresents my EmployerSetup ViewModel, how do I get the name for it in code?  My code right now can only get the FullName if I just take fred.ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) property of the class [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

```
private void ShowExecuted(DataTemplate s) {
  var typeName = s.DataType as Type;
  if (typeName == null)
    return;
  var className = typeName.Name;  // className will be EmployerSetupVM or VendorSetupVM
  ...
}
```

I'd still say passing the `DataTemplate` to the VM just seems strange. I'd just have two commands and switch the command used in the `Button.Style` according to the conditions you got.

If you "have" to use a single `RelayCommand` or the world might end, I'd tend to use a static enum that you can reference from xaml for `CommandParameter` than pass the whole `DataTemplate` object.